# Error z-index en modal

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo mi modal pero al escoger una fecha, la fecha esta por detras del modal y me di cuenta que es por el z-index del datepicker
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi funcion con el datepicker el cual hago que al dar click en el input pueda escoger la fecha pero la fecha sale por detras del formulario.

```
/*=============================
EDITAR FECHA FIN PERIODO LECTIVO
=============================*/
$('#editarFechaFinPeriodoLectivo').datepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    language: "es-ES",
    startView: 2
});
```

y este es mi modal

```
<!--================================
MODAL EDITAR PERIODO LECTIVO
=================================-->
<div class="modal fade"
     id="modalEditarPeriodoLectivo"
     tabindex="-1"
     role="dialog"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm"
         role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form method="post">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Editar Año Lectivo</h5>
                    <button type="button"
                            class="close"
                            data-dismiss="modal"
                            aria-label="Cerrar">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="position-relative form-group">
                        <label for="editarPeriodoLectivo">Año Lectivo</label>
                        <input type="text"
                               name="editarPeriodoLectivo"
                               id="editarPeriodoLectivo"
                               class="form-control"
                               placeholder="2020-2021"
                               required>
                        <input type="hidden"
                               name="editarIDPeriodoLectivo"
                               id="editarIDPeriodoLectivo"
                               required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="position-relative form-group">
                        <label for="editarFechaInicioPeriodoLectivo">Fecha de Inicio del Año
                                                                     Lectivo</label>
                        <input type="text"
                               name="editarFechaInicioPeriodoLectivo"
                               id="editarFechaInicioPeriodoLectivo"
                               class="form-control"
                               placeholder="2020-12-31"
                               required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="position-relative form-group">
                        <label for="editarFechaFinPeriodoLectivo">Fecha de Finalización del Año
                                                                   Lectivo</label>
                        <input type="text"
                               name="editarFechaFinPeriodoLectivo"
                               id="editarFechaFinPeriodoLectivo"
                               class="form-control"
                               placeholder="2020-12-31"
                               required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
                    <button type="button"
                            class="btn btn-danger"
                            data-dismiss="modal">Cerar
                    </button>
                    <button type="submit"
                            class="btn btn-primary">Guardar Cambios
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

quiero saber como puedo hacer que la fecha salga para poder escogerla por delante del modal y ya no por detras ya que asi obviamente no puedo ocuparla, por favor ayudenme con eso.

Comment: Posiblemente el z-index de la clase .modal sea superior al que se está asignando en el datepicker. ¿que valor tiene esta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo lo solucione con una clase del mismo datepicker la cual es la siguiente

```
zIndex:
```

por lo cual me quedaria la funcion asi

```
$('#editarFechaFinPeriodoLectivo').datepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    language: "es-ES",
    zIndex: 1111,
    startView: 2
});
```